# Relationship between the sample mean and population mean

Tags: statistics, means

I'm having difficulty understanding this proof:
$$ \begin{align}
E[\bar{X}] &= E[\frac{X_{1} + ... + X_{n}}{n}] \\ &= \frac{1}{n}(E[X_{1}] +...+E[X_{n}]) \\ &= \mu \end{align}$$

Wouldn't the second line represent 
$$  \frac{1}{n}(E[X_{1}] +...+E[X_{n}]) = \frac{1}{n}(\frac{X_{1} + ... + X_{n}}{n}) =\frac{X_{1} + ... + X_{n}}{n^2}$$
And if so, I'm confused as to how this represents the population mean.

Comment: Why is $E[X_i] = \frac{X_i}{n}$?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that $E[X] = \mu$, so then by linearity of expectation, $$E[X_1+...+X_n] = E[X_1 ]+ ...+ E[X_n] =n\mu$$ so obviously $\frac{1}{n} E[X_1+...+X_n]$ will give just $\mu$.